# Could not load file or assembly, Failed to grant permission to execute

Tags: winforms

*I get following error while running my winform project, though all the reference are added in the project.. Does anybody has solution for it*

```
Could not load file or assembly 'UltraControl, Version=1.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant permission to execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131418)
```

Comment: Sounds like it might be a licencing issue. Are "UltraControls" a 3rd party toolkit?

Comment: Right Ross, UltraControls a 3rd party controls, there cannot be a licensing issue since the same controls working fine in another working solution. I suspect some thing really went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a control to a form, if the control rquires the use of a dll , then it will not consult the references in your project. The designer will look in the GAC to find the required dll.

If the designer cannot find the required file in the GAC then it produces the error you have mentioned.

Register the required dll's in the GAC so the VS IDE designer can access them.